# Why are deprecated methods not reconstructed?

Tags: java, methods, deprecated

From the definition of deprecated:

> A program element annotated `@Deprecated` is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists.

Also, as far as I know, the output of a deprecated method is usually the same as that of the *better alternative*.

So, if a method uses obsolete techniques and can be dangerous, then it should be deleted, and the *better alternative* should be constructed using the **same** method definition.

Hence, **according to me** this would be much better and would not irritate programmers, who tend to use the deprecated methods, with a list of warnings.

Is there any reasons to why this is not done, and why new methods are made with different method signatures or in a different class altogether?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem. Questions about the rationale behind the obsolete attribute's meaning are better suited at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JeroenVannevel this has been [already asked and answered](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/72222/31260) over there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deprecated methods are not simply removed or reimplemented differently because sometimes the signature and the location of a method was as wrong as its functionality.

Consider the class

```
public class Math {
    public static int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
    public static int randomNumber() { return 12; }
}
```

Now someone realizes that the implementation of `randomNumber` is faulty because it actually returns a constant value. Additionally it would be nice to include an `upperBound` as well. And it has nothing to with `Math` and should probably be moved to the class `Random` instead:

```
public class Math {
    public static int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

    @Deprecated
    public static int randomNumber() { return 12; }
}

public class Random {
    public static int randomNumber(int upperBound) { return /* some complex implementation */; }
}
```

What you should always do when marking a question as `@Deprecated` is include the alternative method you should use instead.

And you should not delete or change the originally faulty functionality before not having given a grace period for developers to react to it, i.e. move away from the old method and make use of the new one. Since just removing or changing it without warning would simply break the code of everyone, who may have not realized its actual faulty behavior until recently.

*Final note*: Regarding your statement

> This would be much better and would not irritate programmers, who tend to use the deprecated methods, with a list of warnings.

That is a very bad habit from the get-go. In the definition of done where I work is written that code has to be warning free to be released. We are simply not allowed to use deprecated methods. If you simply choose to ignore the warnings and the deprecated message there is nothing the author of a framework can do about it. The developer who is not willing to adapt can still go ahead, get the source code of the deprecated method and copy it into where he needs it. The `@Deprecated` is a feature for developers who are aware of changes of the framework and are willing and capable of dealing with them. The rest simply does not matter. The `@Deprecated` will get deleted at some point breaking the code of those who were not willing to change anyway.

*Addition regarding the example*: Lets assume that we have `randomNumberBetween0And1` which is wrongly implemented and always returns values between 1 and 2. The users of that function got aware of that bug changed their usage of the method to be `randomNumberBetween0And1() - 1` to compensate for the bug. If you now go ahead and change the implementation to the correct one actually returning something between 0 and 1 that will break the code of everyone who previously compensated your bug via the subtraction of 1 - those people now will get a value between -1 and 0 returned. That is *not* what you want to have happen.

Comment: And that's exactly what bothers me. If `public static int randomNumber() { return 12; }` returns a constant value, then what is the use of keeping it? Just delete it and create a new method with the same definition.

Comment: @PriydarshiSingh you only keep it until you can be quite sure that everybody who previously used it has moved away from it. Deleting it will instantly break every single project that makes us of it - you **have** to give the developer time to react.

Comment: @luk303 If any program makes use of `public static int randomNumber() { return 12; }` and **really** wants a random number, then changing it to `public static int randomNumber() { /*Some code to return a "real" random number*/ }` cannot affect the program in any way. Can it?

Comment: @PriydarshiSingh that was a very simplified example. If you change the return value you will break every user who previously expected the method to return 12 - it does not matter if that implementation was faulty in the first place. You must not simply fix it and change its behavior. That is what developing libraries or APIs is about - you commit yourself - you can no longer freely change your implementation at your own will but always have to keep everyone in mind that relies on your code.

Comment: @PriydarshiSingh I added a last paragraph with a new example, check it out!

Comment: Well now that last paragraph gives me the complete answer. Thanks.

Comment: @PriydarshiSingh you are welcome - it seems like my original example was too simplistic :/

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated methods should not be deleted.

What if a basic method would become deprecated? Are you going to re-write and re-compile every single application you've ever written because you want to update your Java version, or would you prefer that your older applications still work?

It is best that you don't use a deprecated method anymore, that much is true, but in order to keep Java compatible with applications previously written in Java, they should remain there.

> Hence, according to me this would be much better and would not
>   irritate programmers, who tend to use the deprecated methods, with a
>   list of warnings.

If you write decent code, you don't use deprecated methods. Those warnings are there to help you improve your code as soon as a method becomes deprecated. You should only get this warning once, and adjust your code accordingly.

> Any reasons to why this is not done, and why new methods are made with
>   different method definitions or in a different class altogether?

Sometimes the new method is doing exactly the same, sometimes not, and it gets additional functionality. If you would just replace the old method with the new one, you risk changing the behaviour of all existing applications that use the original method.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons for keeping deprecated method name:

- correction of spelling / apply naming convention (but fixing method would break existing code)
- fixed method exists but requires more parameters to work correct. So the one parameter call is kept with a best-guess second parameter. (`java.net.URLDecoder.decode()`)
- no simple fix exists but removing would break code

Answer (score 0):

A method can be deprecated for various reasons, that make your suggestion impossible. Most of the time, it's not because the method is dangerous. It's because there is a better alternative. For example:

- a bad name was chosen for the deprecated method. It has been replaced by a method with a better name: surely keeping the old method is a good thing because it doesn't break all the existing code relying on it, right?
- the design has changed, and there's a better way of doing what the deprecated method did: once again, the deprecated method is not completely broken. It could be broken in some corner cases but you don't want to break all the existing code that use the old method without entering in these corner cases.

Even if the method is dangerous (like Thread.stop(), for example), some people might know that the method is dangerous, are conscious of this fact, but their code works fine anyway and isn't affected by the problem, and rewriting it would cost too much for no tangible benefit. Rewriting the same method stop() without having the problem of the original one is simply impossible, because the problem is inherent to what the method does: stopping a thread without its collaboration.